# Is it a good idea o use the link on the logo to display a sup-header with navigation options?

Tags: navigation, homepage, logos

My website has two different section, one where we do real-time comparison of international money transfer costs, the other where we review different money transfer operators and banks.

We have "two homepages", one for the comparison vertical, one for the review vertical. At the moment, a click on our logo redirect to the "Comparison Homepage", which historically has been our main homepage, but it confuses a lot our users who first landed on the "Review Landing Page" and who cannot find the homepage they first arrived on.

A solution to this problem would be to display a sup-header when a user click on the logo, offering direct access to both services (comparison & review), and a link to both homepages.

I think it would work quite well (currently testing it with users), but I am not sure yet it is a good idea to "hijack" the standard comportement a user may expect when clicking on the logo.

Does someone have experience with that or any insights to share ?

Comment: Definitely not a good idea. The logo should return to the homepage otherwise your users will get confused and a big portion of them will leave.

Comment: Thanks @KristiyanLukanov for your comment. But what if the website has "two homepages" ? 
What would you do for users that arrive on a homepage, navigate through the site, click on the logo, and arrive on a different homepage than the homepage they first arrived on ?

Comment: aren't you confusing *homepage* with *landing page*? How is it even possible to have 2 homepages? edit. see @Evil Closet Monkey answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion that you have "2 home pages" is your problem.

Your website has **one** homepage. It can have 2 major sub-sections (or 3, or 4, ...) *under* that homepage. Your logo should take the user to the *homepage*, from which the user can navigate to the sub-section they need.

Proper page design should allow you to have a *very clear* navigational structure that points to each of the sub-sections. As a user I know exactly where the logo takes me, where the "Comparison Section" link takes me, and the "Transfer Costs" link takes me.

Having the logo display a sub-header popup just makes things more complicated. 1 click - 1 action.

Comment: Thanks ! You're right. A lot of the confusion and frustration from users arriving on this landing page is due to the fact that when they arrive on the homepage, there's no way for them to come back to this landing page from the actual homepage. I'll work on that rather than hijacking the comportement of a click on the logo !